# Ionic 3 prompt with input blank space over keyboard on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keyboard

I'm using a prompt with a text input as follows:

```
const prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: action.action,
    message: action.task_help,
    inputs: [
        {
            name: 'solution',
            placeholder: action.placeholder
        },
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancelar',
        },
        {
            text: 'Terminar',
            handler: data => {
                console.log(data);
                self.action(action.id, data['solution']).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    self.mensaje(response['message']);
                });
            }
        }     
    ]
});
prompt.present();
```

But get a blank space over the keyboard in `Android`. This is not happening with other text inputs, so I guess it has to do with the input inside the prompt.

Any idea or workaround?

[image: Here you can see the blank space]

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `IonicModule.forRoot` in `app.module.ts` file as follows:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  scrollPadding: false,
  scrollAssist: false, 
  autoFocusAssist: false
})
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi Sandy, thank you for your response. Sorry I did not mention it in the post but I do already have this these parameters set to false.